# Django: Insert choice is neglected in form init

Tags: django, forms, field

In my model, I have a CharField with a few choices:

```
SURFACE_CHOICES = (
        ('as', _('Asphalt')),  
        ('co', _('Concrete')), 
        ('ot', _('Other')), )
surface = models.CharField(choices = ROOF_SURFACE_CHOICES, 
        max_length = 2, blank = True, null = True,)
```

I would like to avoid the `-------` choice in the dropdown boxes in the form, and replace it by a more descriptive text.

I used to do it with the following line in the `__init__ method` of `forms.py`

```
def __init__(self, auto_id='%s', *args, **kwargs):
    super(SurfaceUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['surface'].choices.insert(0,('', _('Please choose a surface')))
```

However, in my current app, the first line remains `-------` and is not replaced by the stated text above. Is there a better way to set the blank values?

Answer (score 0):

The `-------` appears because your field has `blank=True`, that is, it is optional. This Django mechanics is kinda hard to understand, but you can override the choices:

```
def __init__(self, auto_id='%s', *args, **kwargs):
    super(SurfaceUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['surface'].choices = [('', _('Please choose a surface'))] + MyModel.SURFACE_CHOICES
```